# How to access QML loaded items from the callback for qmlRegisterSingletonType?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In my main QML file, I have defined a [`MediaPlayer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html). To have a low level access to the media buffer (through `QAudioProbe`), I need to obtain a reference to its [`mediaObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#mediaObject-prop). My C++ backend interfaces with UI through a class registered by `qmlRegisterSingletonType`.

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<BackendInterface>("_", 0, 1, "Backend", backendInterfaceProvider);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

And here's the callback:

```
static QObject *backendInterfaceProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    return new BackendInterface(/* need a QMediaPlayer* here*/);
}
```

**Question**

How to access the QML heirarchy when I am creating my back-end interface (i.e. `BackendInterface`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a singleton type object, it wil be created on first usage, at which time your `MediaPlayer` object might not exist yet.

Instead of trying to retrieve the `MediaPlayer` from QML, make QML "register" the object with C++, i.e. my passing the object to the singleton.

Something like

```
class BackgroundInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void registerMediaPlayer(QObject *player);
};
```

and

```
MediaPlayer {
   id: mediaPlayer

   Component.onCompleted: Backend.registerMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer)
}
```